# Python Swapping Values gives different results on changing order of swap

Tags: python, swap

Input:
`[1,2,3,4]`

Expected Output:

`[2, 1, 3, 4]`

The below code gives the expected result

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[a[0]], a[0] = a[0],a[a[0]]
#Output -> [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

The below code ie, after changing swapping order gives the incorrect output

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[0],a[a[0]] = a[a[0]],a[0]
# Output -> [2, 2, 1, 4]
```

I just switched the order of the assignments. Why does that make a difference?

Edit:
Then why do the two cases below give the same output:

```
a = 1 b= 2 
a,b = b,a #Case1
b,a = a,b #Case2
print(a,b) #=> prints 2,1 for both
```

If the question is not descriptive enough please let me know I will add more comments.
I have tried to make it as simple as possible.
Thanks

Comment: Its because in the second case a[0] comes first, and a becomes [2, 2, 3, 4] before 1 is assigned to  a[a[0]]

Answer (score 0):

It matters because you basically perform two separate assignments. One of those assignements has to be performed first. So if you assign `a[0]` first, then `a[a[0]]` will already work with the new value of `a[0]` to determine the index. If you first assign `a[a[0]]` then the index behaves as expected and only afterwards the value of `a[0]` changes.

Comment: Then why do the two cases below give the same output:

a = 1
b= 2

Case1) a,b = b,a 
Case2) b,a = a,b

print(a,b) => prints 2,1 for both

Comment: @back2back because there is no fancy operations on `a` and `b`. The right hand side is evaluated with their values, and then you simply assign them back in the opposite order. In your case, the variables are co-dependent. By assigning `a[0]` first, you change the meaning of `a[a[0]]`...

Answer (score 0):

Both will return different result, your code means like this

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[a[0]], a[0] = a[0],a[a[0]]
# code above access a[with index a[0]] = 1
# simply means that a[1], a[0] = a[0], a[1]
# and equal with [2, 1, 3, 4]
#Output -> [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

Above code return what your expected result, but how about the incorrect one?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[0],a[a[0]] = a[a[0]],a[0]
# this means a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
# Output -> [2, 2, 1, 4]
```

Explanation:
You define the first `a[0] = a[a[0]]` which equal with `a[0] = a[1] (which current value is 2)` or in simple word `a[0] = 2`.
Next, you call `a[a[0]] = a[0]`  which equal with `a[2] = a[0] (you already define a[0] as 2)` or in simple word `a[2] = 2`
And this give you the result as [2, 2, 1, 4]

For the additional case in swapping value

```
a = 1 b= 2 
a,b = b,a #Case1
b,a = a,b #Case2
print(a,b) #=> prints 2,1 for both
```

This's simple case using variable, and work like common swapping case, but your incorrect sample using list, which are more tricky as I already explained before

Answer (score 0):

Python evaluates first the whole right-hand side, then assigns to the left hand side from left to right. In the first case:

```
tmp1=a[0]      # that is tmp1=1
tmp2=a[a[0]]   # that is tmp2=a[1] that is tmp2=2
a[a[0]]=tmp1   # that is a[1]=1
a[0]=tmp2      # that is a[0]=2
```

In the second case:

```
tmp1=a[a[0]]   # that is tmp1=a[1], that is tmp1=2
tmp2=a[0]      # that is tmp2=1
a[0]=tmp1      # that is a[0]=2
a[a[0]]=tmp2   # that is a[2]=1
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order